# Phantomjs + Angularjs - Can't load module error

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, screenshot

app is running without any problems in production, but when i try to open it with phantomjs in order to take SS i get following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module  is not available! You either misspelled the 
module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that 
you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/nomod..
```

In other hand if I try to open from localhost, this error does not occur, and everything works as expected.

I am using ngAnnotate so DI should not be a problem... Not sure what should I try next. Did anyone had similar issue?